# unable to transfer jsfiddle creation to website

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jsfiddle

I am trying to transfer a jsfiddle creation to my website but I am unable to do so. Here is the link to it:

http://jsfiddle.net/mDc7p/213/

```
/* 
    Eventbrite Examples - organizer event list

    If you copy this code, please set your own API Key in the example below.
    You can request one here: http://www.eventbrite.com/api/key
*/

Eventbrite({'app_key': "HSMTSI2CUDKAXFTXX2"}, function(eb){

    // define a few parameters to pass to the API
    // Options are listed here: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/organizers/organizer_list_events/
    var options = {
        'id'    : "1667880002"
    };

    // provide a callback to display the response data:
    eb.organizer_list_events( options, function( response ){
        $('.event_list').html(eb.utils.eventList( response, eb.utils.eventListRow ));
    });
});
```

I have tried adding the javascript code closed within the `<script type="text/javascript"></script>` tags to my header.php, footer.php and at the bottom of template file (the one which I am using on that particular page but it isn't working. After adding the javascript code, I add `<div class="event_list"></div>` inside the page content area as that's where I want the code to work but it's not working. I am including the jquery library in the header.php file inside the 'head' tags. I also tried the onLoad method by adding the code to the top of the javascript but, sadly, it didn't work. Please help me.

P.S My website is running Wordpress.

Comment: "it didn't work" isn't helpful. Did you have errors in the console ?

Comment: Did you add external resources?

Answer (score 2):

Did you wrap it in document.ready? Your jQuery won't act on elements that don't exist when it loads.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    ...
});
```

or the shorthand

```
$(function() {
    ...
});
```

Comment: +1.  Since JSFiddle will provide the doc ready wrapper by default, this would be easy to miss when transferring to your app.

Comment: I tried your suggestion but it's still not working. It's generating this error inside the console:

'Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function' 

referring to '$(document).ready(function() {'

Comment: Sounds like jQuery isn't loaded, or maybe isn't loaded until after your function.

Comment: okay so I put the code which you've given above at the bottom of my page and loaded the jquery from google's CDN and it's returning this error in the console now:

'Uncaught ReferenceError: Eventbrite is not defined' referring to 'Eventbrite({'app_key': "HSMTSI2CUDKAXFTXX2"}, function(eb){'

Comment: No idea. I don't know what Eventbrite is.

Answer (score 2):

The fiddle is set for the code to run on DOM Ready. So you need to wrap the code in the JavaScript section in an onready call.

```
<script>
$(function() {

    /* 
        Eventbrite Examples - organizer event list

        If you copy this code, please set your own API Key in the example below.
        You can request one here: http://www.eventbrite.com/api/key
    */

    Eventbrite({'app_key': "HSMTSI2CUDKAXFTXX2"}, function(eb){

        // define a few parameters to pass to the API
        // Options are listed here: http://developer.eventbrite.com/doc/organizers/organizer_list_events/
        var options = {
            'id'    : "1667880002"
        };

        // provide a callback to display the response data:
        eb.organizer_list_events( options, function( response ){
            $('.event_list').html(eb.utils.eventList( response, eb.utils.eventListRow ));
        });
    }

);    
});
</script>
```

Comment: you can also put your <script> block at the end of the page

Comment: @DavidFregoli, just copying what the jsFiddle is doing.

Comment: I tried your suggestion too but it's still not working. It's generating this error inside the console: 'Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object Object] is not a function' referring to '$(function() {'

Comment: Did you link to jQuery properly?